# iPad app is not utilising the full screen

Tags: ios, ipad, ios12

I have an iPad application on App Store. App is only supported for iPad. App is not a universal App. I am using launch screen storyboard.

App is working fine on 12.5, 10.5 inch iPad devices. But for 11.0 inch iPad device app (iOS 12.1) is not utilising full screen. App is behaving as iPhone app running on iPad without 2x button.

I know this issue comes when you run iPhone app on iPad. But as my app is iPad only. So not getting what causing this issue.

Is anyone faced similar issue? Please let me know how you fixed it.

Thanks in advance.

Note: 
1 - iPad only build created on environment Xcode 10.0 and iOS 12.0
2 - Just review https://developer.apple.com/ipad/ **Optimizing Your UI** Section.

I don't have 11 inch/pro iPad device. So will iPad app build created on Xcode 10.1 resolved this issue?

Comment: If you don't have an 11" iPad, how do you know it's not running correctly on such a device? Have you actually tested with the 11" iPad simulator in Xcode 10.1?

Comment: My client has 11" iPad. Yes, I moved to Xcode 10.1 and tested on iPad 11" simulator and its working fine. So hopping new App Store release will fix that issue. I think its not an issue, Its apple's default behaviour for new devices. Its scale your app to nearer iPad resolution. Example in 11" it will sale your app to 10.5" resolution. that's causing that black margin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create a view for "that size" then it'll be displayed for the size you created it for. If you created a universal app it would automatically resize itself for the appropriate iOS device. If you create a view for the largest iPad size then it should automatically scale itself down for smaller screens. From the sound of it you created the app for a specific size iPad ignoring the other bit depths available on various models. Even if you want your app for "iPad only" you can do that while still controlling how it scales itself down to say an iPad Air vs iPad Pro.